# I have two #temp tables with the same column names. I want to join the two tables but with an inner join it sends the results like this

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

`--Dt`I have two #temp tables with the same column names. I want to join the two tables but with an inner join it sends the results like this

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G1b8.jpg)

How i want the results to look:

[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBeut.jpg)

The issue with the Union is that it doesnt compare the two results.

Query Used:

```
--Detox  

select distinct client.CL_CASENO , p.PR_NAME , a.AD_EFFDT,a.AD_EXPDT, a.CR_CODE
into #d
from MCCSADPF as sud
inner join  PCHDOCPF as doc on sud.SAP_DOCID = doc.DC_RCDID
inner join v_clients as client on client.CL_RCDID =  doc.DCF_CLTID
inner join v_Providers as p on sud.SAF_APRVID = p.PR_RCDID
left outer join CODCODPF as code on sud.SAF_TDTXTP = code.CO_RCDID
inner join v_Authorizations as a on a.CL_CASENO = client.CL_CASENO
where sud.SAF_APRVID  in ('10118','10115','191853' )
and sud.SAF_TDTXTP = '16774' --Detox  
and CR_CODE in ('H0010') 
and AD_EFFDT >= '2014-10-1' and  AD_EXPDT <= GETDATE()


--Ambulatory  

select distinct client.CL_CASENO , p.PR_NAME , a.AD_EFFDT , a.AD_EXPDT,a.CR_CODE 
into #amb
from MCCSADPF as sud
inner join PCHDOCPF as doc on sud.SAP_DOCID = doc.DC_RCDID
inner join v_clients as client on client.CL_RCDID =  doc.DCF_CLTID
inner join v_Providers as p on sud.SAF_APRVID = p.PR_RCDID
left outer join CODCODPF as code on sud.SAF_TDTXTP = code.CO_RCDID
inner join v_Authorizations as a on a.CL_CASENO = client.CL_CASENO
where sud.SAF_APRVID  in ('191847','10115','191853') 
and sud.SAF_TDTXTP in ('16778') --OutPatient
and CR_CODE in('H0020')
and AD_EFFDT >= '2014-10-1' and  AD_EXPDT <= GETDATE()  

----------------------------------------------------------------------
--JOIN--

Select * from #d as d
inner join #amb as a on d.CL_CASENO = a.CL_CASENO
where d.AD_EFFDT <= a.AD_EFFDT
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: With your statement "Union with Compare" , I think you want Full outer join..

Comment: Thank you for the link Sean

Comment: Aditya, A full outer join will give me All data results..i only need the clients that have gone through both the detox and then ambulatory

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is patients who exist in both tables, your query is almost right.  All you need to to is to grab the first table.

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM #d d
JOIN #amb a ON d.CL_CASENO = a.CL_CASENO
WHERE d.AD_EFFDT <= a.AD_EFFDT
```